# how to run the find command in another directory

Tags: bash, shell

I m trying to write a shell script which will go to a particular directory and deleted the files older than 4 days owned by a particular user(pwadmin). I know the command of deleting which is as below :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime +4 -type f -user "pwadmin" -delete
```

But my requirement is that this command is to be executed in some other directory let's say the directory is :

cd /admin/data/inventory

How to write a shell for that ?

Comment: `find` takes paths as arguments.

Comment: @Aviator : `man find` . See there the explanation of _starting point_.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the find command by providing the path like this

```
find /admin/data/inventory -maxdepth 1 -mtime +4 -type f -user "pwadmin" -delete
```